# Paypal native checkout sdk android paypal button does not render after one payment completion or cancellation

Tags: android, kotlin, paypal, sdk

I'm currently using the Paypal Native Checkout SDK https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/android/. Everything works fine
for the first time, but if I complete or cancel a paypal payment, the button does not render
again, the log returns the error I/PaymentButtonEligibility: eligibility: Error.

Does anyone know the solution?

```
class App: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val config = CheckoutConfig(
        application = this,
        clientId = "....",
        environment = Environment.SANDBOX,
        returnUrl = "my.com.testpaypal://paypalpay",
        currencyCode = CurrencyCode.MYR,
        userAction = UserAction.PAY_NOW,
        paymentButtonIntent = PaymentButtonIntent.CAPTURE,
        settingsConfig = SettingsConfig(
            loggingEnabled = true
        )
    )
    PayPalCheckout.setConfig(config)
}
```

}

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityTestBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityTestBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.btnPay.setup(
            createOrder = CreateOrder { createOrderActions ->
                val order = Order(
                intent = OrderIntent.CAPTURE,
                appContext = AppContext(
                    userAction = UserAction.PAY_NOW
                ),
                purchaseUnitList = listOf(
                    PurchaseUnit(
                        //items = List<Items>(1) { _ -> },

                        amount = Amount(
                            currencyCode = CurrencyCode.MYR,
                            value = "12"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            createOrderActions.create(order)
        },
        onApprove = OnApprove { approval ->
            approval.orderActions.capture { captureOrderResult ->
                Log.i("CaptureOrder", "CaptureOrderResult: $captureOrderResult")
            }
        },
        onCancel = OnCancel {
            Log.i("OnCancel", "Buyer canceled the PayPal experience.")
        },
        onError = OnError { errorInfo ->
            Log.i("OnError", "Error: $errorInfo")
        }
    )
}
```

}

1. [Button can render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoC6X.jpg)
2. [paypal native checkout sdk ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA0dJ.jpg)
3. [Button can't render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zsy2.jpg)

Comment: this is the error im getting "2021-09-09 02:26:32.540 6602-6602/my.com.testpaypal I/PaymentButtonEligibility: eligibility: Error"

Comment: Re-create the button as needed, don't use the same one

Comment: @PrestonPHX may I know how sir